# Do Either Ray Park, Bryan Singer, Gordon Smith or Famke Janssen Discuss the Toad vs Jean Grey scene from the first X-Men movie in his book Unmasked?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe

Main reason I am asking is that I know that Gordon Smith has a book called Unmasked: Volume 1, where it discusses various different films, and I was wondering if anyone involved with the first X-Men movie discusses the Toad vs Jean Grey fight?

The book is $26.00 on Amazon and I really don't want to invest in the book if it doesn't cover that scene.

Main interest is Famke Janssen a few years ago mentioned that she had issues with Taken 2 due to claustrophobia and I'm pretty sure she had a slime mold over her face for the scene

Comment: It might be worth checking to see if your library has a copy, or can request it via Inter Library Loan.

Answer (score 2):

A search in the Kindle edition (substantially cheaper at 7 Euro at least on the German Amazon page) does not return results for "Toad" or "Famke Janssen", so apparently not.

In fact the book mentions X-Men only in a single sentence (referring to wolverines claws) and the appendix with list of nominations for movie awards.